# OpenQuery Statement could not be prepared

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, openquery

I have a dynamic SQL query using openquery giving me a syntax error.  The statement will run just fine when run through query window (sans the dynamic SQL) but when trying to run through SQL Agent it fails with -

> Statement(s) could not be prepared. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 8180)  Incorrect syntax near '='. [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 102)
>
> OLE DB provider "SQLNCLI11" for linked server "_________" returned message "Deferred prepare could not be completed.". [SQLSTATE 01000] (Error 7412).  The step failed.

```
SELECT @SQL = N'
Insert into ' + @ToDatabase + '.dbo.UserUsages
(Date, AppCode, UserName, EriAccountId, [Count], SubscriptionCode)

SELECT Timestamp
, Appcode
, Username
, EriAccountId
, [Count]
, SubscriptionCode
FROM openquery([' + @ServerSource + '],
''[Timestamp] = CAST([Timestamp] AS date)
, AppCode
, UserName
, EriAccountId
, [Count]= COUNT(MethodName) 
, SubscriptionCode
FROM ' + @FromDatabase + '.dbo.[Log]
'
SELECT @SQL2 = N'
WHERE   
(MethodName = ''''GetSalaryTable'''') OR            
(MethodName = ''''GetSalaryByLevelTable'''') OR     
(MethodName = ''''GetEmployees'''') OR              
(MethodName = ''''GetBenchmarkList'''') OR          
(MethodName = ''''GetAdvancedReport'''') OR         
(MethodName = ''''GetGeoList'''') OR            
(MethodName = ''''GetComparableCompanies'''') OR    
(MethodName = ''''GetComparisonList'''') OR     
(MethodName = ''''GetGAChart'''') OR            
(MethodName = ''''GetOesData'''') OR            
(MethodName = ''''GetTwoCityComparison'''') OR      
(MethodName = ''''GetSalaryFromC3Norms'''') OR      
(MethodName = ''''GetCoLs'''') OR                   
(MethodName = ''''GetPerDiems'''') OR               
(MethodName = ''''GetTwoCityValues'''')  OR         
(MethodName = ''''DisabilityFilterJobs'''') OR      
(MethodName = ''''ProcessAnalysis'''') OR           
(MethodName = ''''GetFormTabs'''') OR               
(MethodName = ''''GetReportDataForJob'''')          


GROUP BY CAST(Timestamp AS date), AppCode, UserName, EriAccountId, 
SubscriptionCode
HAVING      
(SubscriptionCode IS NOT NULL) 
AND (CAST(Timestamp AS date)) BETWEEN ''''' + 
CONVERT(NVARCHAR,CAST(DateAdd(dd, +1, @startDate) AS DATE))  +''''' and 
CAST(DateAdd(dd, -1, GETDATE()) AS DATE) '') 

'
```

Comment: Have you examined the SQL statement that results? It looks like it has far too many quotation marks and some appear to be imbalanced.

Comment: Dynamic SQL and openquery require that many quotations.  It's absurd in my opinion

Comment: I think you need a `SELECT` before `[Timestamp]`.

Comment: @RazvanSocol Wow that's it!  I completely missed that.  Thank you, if you want to put that in an answer I will accept.

Answer (score 0):

You need a `SELECT` before `[Timestamp]`.